# Java Iterate Over a Map with SimpleEntry

Tags: java, treemap

I have a TreeMap with 3 entries, of the following type:

```
Map<String, Entry<String, String>> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Entry<String, String>>();
```

I populate the map with the following code:

```
SimpleEntry<String, String> simpleEntry = new SimpleEntry<String, String>("", "");

for (int i = 0; i < listSites.size(); i++) {

        String stringkey = listSites.get(i);
        String stringValue = listSitesDesc.get(i);
        String stringLink = listSitesLinks.get(i);

        entry = new SimpleEntry<String, String>(stringValue, stringLink);
        actionMap.put(stringkey, simpleEntry);

}
```

This works just as expected.

My issue is how to retrieve the individual values form the sorted TreeMap.

EDITED :

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Entry<String, String>> entrySet : treeMap.entrySet()) {

        String key = entrySet.getKey();
        String valueKey = simpleEntry.getKey();
        String valueValue = simpleEntry.getValue();
}
```

This prints the correct values for the key, like:

```
 key = one , two , three , four , five .....
```

But I am getting the wrong values for valueKey and valueValue, like:

```
valueKey = bear , bear , bear , bear , bear ...
```

instead of :

```
valueKey = dog , cat , monkey, tiger , bear ....
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4):

`Map.keySet()` (unsurprisingly) returns the *keys*, not the *values*.

To get the *values*, use (again, unsurprisingly) `Map.values()`.

To iterate over all the key/value pairs, ie the *entries*:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Entry<String, String>> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
    // showing how to get at the parts:
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String valueKey = entry.getValue().getKey();
    String valueValue = entry.getValue().getValue();

}
```

---

This is an unusual way to approach whatever problem you're trying to solve, because each key has only one value, so you have "key -> key -> value", which is the same as just "keykey -> value". Consider dispensing with the outer layer map and using just `Map<String, String>`, and/or using classes with (named) fields to store your data.

Comment: thanks for your help, but I might have been a little hasty in accepting the answer. Playing around with the code, I noted something odd: the print values are not as expected. There seems to be no method like getValue().getKey() and  Kindly have a look at my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

First, take @Bohemian's answer, that's what does what you want. and any future googles.  It's not working because you have a bug :D (which is why we all come to stack overflow, depending on your definition of bug)

<strike>SimpleEntry simpleEntry = new SimpleEntry("", "");</strike>

...

actionMap.put(stringkey, <strike>simpleEntry</strike> *entry*);

does that help?

Comment: Not really :-), I need three individual printable values, stringOne, stringTwo, strigThree ...

Comment: sure, one second

Comment: Actually, @Bohemian put the code in i was going to. ;)  make sense or need more of an explanation on Bohemian's answer?

Comment: I have edited my question. There are some issues with the printed values of the SimpleEntry. Would you mind having a look?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question...

> But how do I get the second and third values of the map, those defined
>   by the SimpleEntry?

Since it's not clear exactly what you're looking for (which is probably why you weren't able to find an answer) here are a few (but not all) ways to iterate over a map:

```
// I'm changing your map a little to avoid confusion over the word 'Entry'.
Map<String, SimpleEntry<String, String>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, SimpleEntry<String, String>> ent: treeMap.entrySet())
{
  String key = ent.getKey();
  SimpleEntry val - ent.getValue();
}
```

If you're using Java 8 or later...

```
// Using your original map
Map<String, Entry<String, String>> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
treeMap.forEach((key, value) ->
{
  // key is a String, value is an Entry<String, String>>
});

// Explicit parameter types can increase code readability
treeMap.forEach((String key, Entry<String, String>> value) ->
{
  // Have fun with the contents of your map!
});
```

Comment: I have edited my question to make it more specific what I want to achieve. I have 3 values in my map. There are some issues with the printed values of the SimpleEntry. Would you mind having a look?